# Use class instance as parent class in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a better understanding of python class system. This question is intended only to satisfy my curiosity.

Is it possible to use somehow a class instance as a parent class for another class. So far what I tried to do is

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()

class B(a):
    pass
```

and it gives following error: `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

```
class Meta(type):
    pass

class A:
    pass

a = A()

class B(a, metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

and it gives this error `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

I'm wondering, is it possible to somehow proxy all of the class instance methods to metaclass, so my instance would behave as a class

Comment: It's unclear *why* you'd want to ever do this, but if you *really* want it google "prototypes in python"

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use somehow a class instance as a parent class for another class

Well, actually that's always the case since classes ARE instances (of their metaclass). But then the class of the instance you want to use as a parent class (yeah, re-read it thrice...) must behave as if it was a genuine metaclass - which can rapidily become impractical.

> I'm wondering, is it possible to somehow proxy all of the class instance methods to metaclass, so my instance would behave as a class

There might be a way indeed (overriding `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()`), but devil is in the details and chances are that by the time you make this rube goldberg contraption "kind-of-work-with-severe-limitations-and-corner-cases", you will wonder if that was really worth the pain.

Note that OTHO both composition/delegation and dynamic (runtime) creation / modification of classes is absurdly easy in Python so I can hardly think of a problem that would be better solved by (ab)using an instance as a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

OK, so it is possible to hack if you have control over the base class (either using metaclasses or `__init_subclass__` (python 3.6 or later))

```
class A:
    x = 1
    def __init_subclass__(cls, inst, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for k, v in vars(inst).items():
            if k not in dir(cls):  # i.e. don't override but remove if you want to
                setattr(cls, k, v)

a = A()
a.y = 2   

class B(A, inst=a):
    pass

B.x # --> 1
B.y # --> 2
```

---

You're sort of on the right tracks with your second example. Yes it is possible.

```
class Meta(type): pass
class A(metaclass=Meta): pass
class B(A): pass

issubclass(B, A) # --> True
isinstance(B, Meta) # --> True
```

Thats because `A` is an instance of `Meta` (thats what a metaclass means, a class whose instance is also a class). Hence `B` is a subclass of an instance of `Meta`.

So yes, you could set for example

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         cls.x = 1
         super().__init__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class A(Meta):
    def __init__(self):
         self.y = 2

A.x  # 1 (acts as an instance of Meta)
a = A()
a.y  # 2 (acts as an instance of A)
a.x  # AttributeError (does not act as an instance of Meta)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP clearly wants some form of prototypal inheritance a la JavaScript.

Comment: @JaredSmith You seem very sure of that. What makes you think so?

Comment: Because that's what "inherit from a class instance" means: take some given object x and use it as a template for stamping out more xs dynamically, and indeed the OPs response to Matias Cicero's answer confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance has a `__class__` attribute that refers to the underlying `class` structure.

Knowing this, you can actually do the following:

```
class A(object):
   def foo(self):
      return 'hello'

a = A()

class B(a.__class__):
    pass

b = B()
print(b.foo()) # Prints 'hello'
```

Alternatively, you can also use [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
class B(type(a)):
    pass

b = B()
print(b.foo()) # Prints 'hello'
```

Comment: Yes, I know about `__class__` attribute, but as I said in the question, I want to inherit a class from class instance, not from its class

Comment: @KirillCherepanov I'm not quite following. What exactly do you mean by inheriting from an instance? May you provide an example and desired output?

Comment: The first code snippet is something I want to achieve. Again, I don't see any practical usage for this, I just want to know if it's possible and how it can be done

Comment: @KirillCherepanov this only makes sense in the context of objects being able to accept new properties dynamically at runtime: otherwise they *only* have the properties defined by their class(es) and an instance is uninteresting as a template for new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance needs to be a `type` in order to be used in inheritance chains. For example:

```
class A(type):
    pass

a = A(str)  # you need to pass the type's `type` to the construcor

class B(a):
    pass
```

That being said, there's little, if no practical application for this that I can think of - or rather whatever you achieve this way will be easier and more *Pythonic* to achieve through normal inheritance and metaclasses.